# Home gateway, Wireless Router, Port forwarding issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port-forwarding

Basic info: (Fiber Optics)
 1. Home gateway : Huawei HG8244T
 2. Wireless Router : Linksys X2000
 3. Old Wireless Router : Linksys EA2700 N600

Story: 
    Before upgrading to Linksys X2000 port forwarding was working just fine as i have to port forward from the Gateway interface itself and it was a breeze,
The old router i have screw it up(was updating firmware "take long time so i reset/unplug the router") Now it doesn't broadcast any SSID nor i can connect to it, Now here is the catch: i have to port forward both gateway and linksys X2000 but it never worked, i have tried DMZ, turning router firewall off and other thing that failed, "***Keep in mind before upgrading the router DHCP was supplied directly from the gateway but now it is supplied from the linksys X2000***" , also DHCP range in gateway start from 192.168.100.x to .254 and the linksys X2000 start from 192.168.1.x to .254(Not changeable only last digits), i have read that bridging the linksys X2000 will allow port forwarding to work but i cant use it as the connection from gateway to router uses Ethernet not ADSL.

So i'm hoping to find some help from you guys, Thanks alot.

PS: Internet is working using X2000
PS:I also heard about Reverse tunneling, but i don't have any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly the Huawei HG8244T is your ADSL modem. You should try to forward all traffic to the Linksys and let it handle the port forwarding to the separate devices. Maybe there is an option to set the Huawei in bridge mode or set the IP-address of the Linksys as an 'exposed host'. In this situation you should let the Linksys handle the routing, firewall and act as DHCP server for your internal network. Make sure no other devices are connected to the Huawei but all are connected to the Linksys.

Comment: "You should try to forward all traffic to the Linksys and let it handle the port forwarding to the separate devices." This is it, all i have to do was finding the DHCP address assigned to linksys and DMZ it, i find it by looking what device connected to Ethernet port. now all port forwarding is handled by linksys. Thanks alot you made my day :)